# runat="server" Not Working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, runatserver

I have the following markup on my ASCX control:

```
<a href="ProposalDetails.aspx?pid=<%= Request.QueryString["pid"] %>&tab=Proposal&view=RoomBlock" id="RoomBlockLink" runat="server">
    Room Block
</a>
```

It seems to work fine, but if I attempt to modify this control from C# code:

```
RoomBlockLink.Attributes.Add("style", "color: #808080; font-style: italic;");
```

I get the Intellisense and compiler error:

> The name 'RoomBlockLink' does not exist in the current context

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attribute:

```
runat="server"
```

Is only effective when all the root to this element has this attribute.

Comment: Yeah, that appears to be the issue. Wasn't aware of that. Thanks!

Comment: I understand that this is an old answer, but what does this mean? can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with web page controls.  They were resolved when I changed my project from a Web Application to a Web Site. Please see [Code behind does not recognize my control variable on its aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803170/code-behind-does-not-recognize-my-control-variable-on-its-aspx-page/10898057#10898057).